# Is it possible to change the parameters to a method in a class annotated with @Retryable in the retry event?

Tags: micronaut

I have a singleton class annotated with `@Retryable`. Within this we are making calls with a `@Client` with an auth token passed in as a parameter.

If the auth has expire we wish to re-auth and then retry the method call with the updated token.

We handle the `RetryEvent` and get a new token but we cannot update the original method call parameters. The method returns a `Single`.

Something like this:

```
@Retryable
@Singleton
class test {
    @Inject TestRestClient testRestClient

   Single<E> getStuff(AuthClient auth, String param) {
      testRestClient.apiCall(auth.token, param).map{ stuff -> 
         do some stuff as E
      }
   }
}

// Retry Handler

@Singleton
class AuthRetryEventListener implements ApplicationEventListener<RetryEvent> {

    @Inject
    AuthService authService

    @Override
    void onApplicationEvent(RetryEvent event) {
        MutableArgumentValue argumentValue = event.source.parameters.find{it.value.value.class in AuthClient.class}?.value
        if(argumentValue){
            AuthClient authClient = argumentValue.value as AuthClient
            authService.refresh(authClient)
            argumentValue.setValue(authClient)
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to go about this? How can I make the method call again with the updated parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire point of `@Retryable` is to retry the original call. What you're trying to do does not fit into the use case for `@Retryable`. This would most likely be a better fit to be implemented in a filter.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.